# How to upload data with cyrillic in Oracle ADW?

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle19c

I started to use Oracle ADW.
I want to upload csv file with cyrillic symbols using Sql Developer Web interface. But instead of expected text I get the next
[image]

How should I upload data?

Comment: Why do you consider AL32UTF8 not as appropriate? It's the best you can have.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I understand, that I asked question incorrect. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to look at two points:

1. What is the encoding of your CSV file? For Cyrillic it could be typically `ISO 8859-5`, `Codepage 1251`, `UTF-8` or even `UTF-16` but I don't know.
2. You need to tell the Oracle database the encoding. Typically this is done via the `NLS_LANG` environment variable.

I never used the Sql Developer Web interface, so I don't know where to set it. Perhaps you cannot change it and the tool forces your CSV file to be encoded as UTF-8. IN this case you have to convert your CSV file into UTF-8 before you upload it.